# dumps() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: json, python-3.x

```
import json
a={"name": "abc", "age": 20, "sal": 20000}
with open("test.json", "w") as p1:
    json.dumps(a, p1)
```

Below is the error
***`dumps()` takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given***

*Python version*: 3.6.4

Answer (score 17):

you need to use `dump` and not `dumps`

as the docs says, the `dump` function turns it to json and then streams it on into a file, meanwhile `dumps` turns it into str.

you can read about it more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)